# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string errors coming when trying to get file extension?

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-6

when uploading a file from html page and need to get the file extension. But the uses function showing an error. What are procedure to solve that issue?

```
public function downloadAttendance(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'attendance_date' => 'required',
            'attendance_file' => 'required',
        ]);

        $date = $request->attendance_date ? database_formatted_date($request->attendance_date) : null;
        $file = $request->attendance_file;
        $file_ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        dd($file_ext);
        $file_path = $file->getRealPath();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$file = $request->file('attendance_file');
$file_ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting string when using
`$request->file`
You can get file by using this method,

```
$file = $request->file('file_key');
```

refer this link for more information.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads